# Intricate Rails 3 Routing Configuration - Can routes.rb Access Initializers' Code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm converting a bunch of landing pages written in php in order to add them to my RoR-based site (that's been live for more than 2 years now). These landing pages are divided into several versions, but unfortunately there is no consistency as far as URL names go. My problem is that the php pages I'm converting already have a high page rank, therefore I'd like to keep their URLs exactly the way it was.

I'm not sure how to set my routes.rb so that example.com/* will always go to my homepage; however, when (* == 'name-of-one-of-the-landing-pages') Rails will route to a separate controller, where a specific action will determine which page to render, based on an Initializer and the params hash, all this while the URL is, as mentioned, identical to what it was prior to the php-to-RoR conversion, namely www.example.com/name_of_landing_page, rather than www.example.com/*controller_name*/name_of_landing_page.

I know of the :path property that enables one to exclude the controller name from the path if passed an empty string (i.e. `resources :examples, :path => ''`), but that doesn't quite solve the entire problem.

I was thinking about writing an initializer that would hold a hash of all relevant landing pages, and using constraints in routes.rb to check against it, but I'm not sure if this kind of implementation is possible and how to go about it. A code example would be much appreciated.

Is there some kind of syntax for routes.rb that would enable me to do so, or perhaps a better solution?

Comment: Well, that's what initalizers are for -- to initialize your app in the state you want it to be in. The initalizers will get loaded first before the routes.rb file.

Comment: @treehau5, well, when you put it that way :) I figured that's feasible, was actually looking for a better implementation, perhaps one that is more 'Railsy'. Keeping hundreds of page names in an initializer seems a bit dirty to me.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question: in routes.rb, inside the do/end block you will actually be in the context of `ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper`, so no you won't. But, right after that block, you are back to the top level of your application and will have access to whatever variables you initialized inside your initializers, however, that code might be better suited to go in application.rb.

The only thing you should be doing in routes.rb is defining routes.

You could also handle the request for the legacy pages in rack

```
def call(env)
  request = Rack::Request.new(env)
  return [200, {"Location" => request.url("http://www.example.com")} if request.host == "www.oldpage.com"
end
```

More info here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/222-rack-in-rails-3

Comment: thanks for the input! Is there no way to work around the scoping problem inside routes.rb? All I want to do is have one specific route check for the existence of a key inside the Initializer's hash. Something along the lines of: 
`match '/:page_name' => 'controller#action', :as => :something, :constraints => lambda { |r| MyInitializer::Relevant_Hash.has_key?(r.params[:page_name]) }`

Unfortunately, as you mentioned, right now I'm getting an error saying 'uninitialized constant MyInitializer' (ironically).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why complex things involved. Setting such should be very simple in route.

Suppose your have a controller to handle static pages named "PagesController"

```
get 'name-of-one-of-the-landing-pages-a', to: 'pages#a'
get 'name-of-one-of-the-landing-pages-b', to: 'pages#b'
```

There is no need to add controller names in the path. You can control all of them.